# Data Recovery using testDisk failing

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, forensics

Continuation of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/286481/how-to-recover-my-c-partition/286547#286547):

I am trying to recover an accidentally formatted partition using TestDisk.

After selecting the **partition** and selecting **Undeleted**, it says, **No deleted file found.**

[image]

[image]

I know it's a silly question, but I just want to make sure that the data really is out of reach. Or is there anything I can do to recover them?

I tried to repair my partition table using `bootrec.exe/FixMBR` and `bootrec.exe/FixBoot`; can this be the reason why TestDisk doesn't work any more? I haven't written anything on that partition.

Are there any low level approaches to retrieve all the lost data?

Comment: hm.. that looks nothing like what i saw on the recovery process, using this howto http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step - in this situation you are supposed to run the deeper analysis process to try to find it again.

Comment: I started using, Ontrack EasyRecovery Pro and It successfully recovered some files. But, I sill want to make a image of the damaged partition. What software can I use to make image that should be widely recognizable by many recovery softwares?

Comment: Successfully retrieved around 14GB of my documentations :)

Comment: ddrescue is probably your best bet. http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html

Comment: @iamcreasy - How did you end up recovering your files? Did you use TestDisk or OnTrack?

Comment: I used Ontrack EasyRecovery.